# iOS Location Services Enabled/Disabled event when application closed

Tags: ios, location, cllocationmanager

I'm currently using `CLLocationManager` to always track geofences even when the application is in the background. I can't seem to find a way to listen for when location services is enabled/disabled.

Is it possible to listen for a location service enable/disable event or when location is enabled/disabled for your specific application while the application is closed?

Please note I'm using Xamarin, but Objective-C code is fine.

```
public class LocationManager
{
    protected CLLocationManager locationManager;

    public LocationManger()
    {
        this.locationManager = new CLLocationManger();

        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0))
        {
            locationManager.RequestAlwaysAuthorization();
        }


        // ... get array of CLCircularRegion and start listening to each

        // locationManager events...
        locationManager.RegionEntered += (sender, e) => { /*stuff*/ };
        locationManager.RegionLeft += (sender, e) => { /*stuff*/ };
        locationManager.DidDetermineState += (sender, e) => { /*stuff*/ };
        //locationaManager.SomeSortOfLocationServiceEnableDisableEvent += (sender, e) => { /*stuff*/ };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A call to the class method `[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]` returns a `BOOL` indicating whether location services are enabled or not.

If the user disables location services, `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:` will be called on a `CLLocationManagerDelegate`.

Therefore, if you have a class conform to `CLLocationManagerDelegate` and implement `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:`, you should be able to handle the disable event by the user.

Comment: Yes but that doesn't tell me when location services are changed.

Comment: I’ve updated my answer with the delegate method that handles a change in authorization status. Does that help?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work perfectly, but it looks like it's the best iOS has to offer. Thanks Daniel.

Comment: No problem, Jared. I’m glad you could at least get something from iOS to fit your need.